# How to declare array of structs in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I am having trouble declaring an array of structs prior to populating them with data.

My struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct {
  uint8_t * p_data;     ///< Pointer to the buffer holding the data.
  uint8_t   length;     ///< Number of bytes to transfer.
  uint8_t   operation;  ///< Device address combined with transfer direction.
  uint8_t   flags;      ///< Transfer flags (see @ref NRF_TWI_MNGR_NO_STOP).
} nrf_twi_mngr_transfer_t;
```

And in my code I am trying to declare the array like this:

```
struct nrf_twi_mngr_transfer_t start_read_transfer[10];
```

However I get a compile error:

> array type has incomplete element type 'struct nrf_twi_mngr_transfer_t'

I have searched around as I thought should be a common thing, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Maybe because one of the elements is a pointer?  But that pointer should be a fixed size right?

Many thanks

Comment: `nrf_twi_mngr_transfer_t start_read_transfer[10];` - i.e. no need for `struct` there, you are already typedefing it.

Comment: There is no `struct nrf_twi_mngr_transfer_t` type defined. Your `typedef` is defining type named `nrf_twi_mngr_transfer_t`, which happens to be a `struct`.

Comment: Drop the strict keyword when you use the typedef name.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like some explanations are in order. This code

```
typedef struct {
    //...
} nrf_twi_mngr_transfer_t;
```

Already defines a **type** which can be used directly. In contrast,

```
struct nrf_twi_mngr_transfer_struct {
    //...
};
```

Would define a struct name, and to access it you'd need to indicate that you are referring to a struct.

As a result, given two definitions above, you should define your arrays differently:

```
nrf_twi_mngr_transfer_t arr[10]; // if using typedef
struct nrf_twi_mngr_transfer_struct arr2[10]; // if using struct with no typedef
```

And just in case you are wondering,

```
struct {
    //...
} nrf_twi_mngr_transfer_obj;
```

Defines an object of anonymous struct type.

Comment: Perfect.  i was overthinking it..  Thank you!